# Spring Boot failing to connect to Testcontainer Cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to connect to `TestContainer Cassandra` on my `Spring Boot` app, but it fails. I've tried many different approaches, but it seems that it cannot connect. Not sure what or where is the problem.

At the bottom I added two Docker Container's last logs.

**First approach:**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class MyServiceTests {

    @Container
    private static final CassandraContainer<?> cassandra = new CassandraContainer<>("cassandra:latest")
            .withExposedPorts(9042)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .withReuse(true);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThat(cassandra.isRunning()).isTrue();
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```java
# Cassandra
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=test_keyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

Error:

```java
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 2 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b4d149d): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)], Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=592f89be): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraSession(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 151 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:356) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:193) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:124) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
        Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:356) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:193) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:124) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57) ~[java-driver-core-4.13.0.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.73.Final.jar:4.1.73.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
        Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

**Second approach:**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class MyServiceTests {

    @Container
    static CassandraContainer<?> cassandra = new CassandraContainer<>("cassandra:latest");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void cassandraProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        cassandra.start();

        registry.add("spring.cassandra.contact-points", cassandra::getContactPoint);
        registry.add("spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter", cassandra::getLocalDatacenter);
        registry.add("spring.cassandra.port", cassandra::getFirstMappedPort);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThat(cassandra.isRunning()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Error:

```java
Same as in First approach.
```

**Third approach:**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MyServiceTests.Initializer.class)
public class MyServiceTests {

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            GenericContainer<?> cassandra =
                    new GenericContainer<>("cassandra:latest").withExposedPorts(9042);

            cassandra.start();

            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=" + cassandra.getHost(),
                    "spring.data.cassandra.port=" + cassandra.getMappedPort(9042)
            ).applyTo(applicationContext);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Error:

```java
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:542)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [64834] should be listening)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:102)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:52)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:953)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:485)
    ... 82 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

**First Docker container logs:**
[image]

**Second Docker container logs:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withExposedPorts` is not really needed because it is already implemented by CassandraContainer already. `withStartupTimeout` could be needed if you have to wait more to have a container ready and `withReuse(true)` maybe needed if you want to keep a container running even after your tests are done, btw, this is an experimental feature. Also, `withExposedPorts` means exposing cassandra's port on a random port and that's the reason why the first approach didn't work. The code provided for the first approach is hardcoding the port. About the second approach, it should use `spring.data.cassandra` prefix if you are using spring boot 2.x, spring version 3.x uses `spring.cassandra`. And finally, the third approach is
missing `spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter`

The code is mixing properties with prefix `spring.cassandra` and `spring.data.cassandra`. The first is used at spring boot 3.0 and the last one is in 2.x. Careful with that.

I would suggest looking at the following [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/DataCassandraTestIntegrationTests.java).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your given example actually worked (only changed `spring.casssandra` to `spring.data.cassandra`), awesome. But my first approach looks cleaner for me. I did remove `withExposedPorts`, `withStartupTimeout` and `withReuse` and I only was left with one line of `= new CassandraContainer<>`, but I still do receive the same error. Is it because of hardcoding port, as you mentioned? Can I stay with my first approach without `DynamicPropertySource` and `TestConfiguration` in your given example and how? Thank you.

Comment: using hardcoded ports are not recommended if you want to run parallel tests. If your tests is still failing because of `Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042` then is due to the hardcoded port. `DynamicPropertySource` as an integration point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Lastly, it's not working when `Autowiring` some dependencies/services. If I removed `@DataCassandraTest` along with `Testcontainers` it's fine. How to properly enable `@SpringBootTest` along with `@Testcontainers` so I could `@Autowire` my services? Thank you.

Comment: `@DataCassandraTest` only enables spring data insfrastructure. Switching to `@SpringBootTest` should start your app controllers, services.